# Create multiple (two) source with chartit in Django

Tags: django, charts

I'm using chartit in a django project.
I have a models (ReadingSensor) with the following attributes:

- id_sensor
- date_time
- value

I want to create a line chart with several lines for different `id_sensors`

for example:

`ReadingSensor.objects.filter(id_sensor=2)
ReadingSensor.objects.filter(id_sensor=1)`

For a single model we have:

```
ds = DataPool(
       series=
        [{'options': {
            'source': MonthlyWeatherByCity.objects.all()},
          'terms': [
            'month',
            'houston_temp', 
            'boston_temp']}
         ])


cht = Chart(
        datasource = ds, 
        series_options = 
          [{'options':{
              'type': 'line',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
              'month': [
                'boston_temp',
                'houston_temp']
              }}],
        chart_options = 
          {'title': {
               'text': 'Weather Data of Boston and Houston'},
           'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                   'text': 'Month number'}}})
```

Documentation: http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/

I consulted the documentation but found no suggestive example to help me. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: please post your code!

Comment: I added now. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Actually the example is on the site you provide, please check this link: http://chartit.shutupandship.com/demo/chart/multi-table-same-x/

The idea is just to add more items with `options` and `terms` to the `series` list when constructing `DataPool` object and adjust the `terms` in `series_options` when constructing `Chart` object accordingly.

Then you may find it's helpful to adjust the field name for the case when two data sources have the fields with the same name, the detailed document regarding to this issue is here: http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/apireference.html#datapool